# What is the size parameter of the direct red 80 molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry

**Basic information:**
CAS number: 2610-10-08
Molecular formula: C45H26N10Na6O21S6
Molecular weight: 1373.07
Structural formula:
[image]

**For example**:
For congo red whose structural formula is demonstrated below, the molecule size can be expressed as ca. 2.56 × 0.73 × 1.13 nm3 (could be "length × width × height"?) (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.memsci.2021.119635)
[image]

I found a research article containing the information I need along with the parameters of Columbia blue, methyl blue, congo red, amaranth, and sunset yellow. They are in the *supporting information*.
https://doi.org/10.1007/s12598-022-02153-4
Hope it could help the ones in need.